# Prove that $GLB\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \Bbb{N}\}=0$.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $glb\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \Bbb{N}\}=0$.
I wanna prove it formally buy I have difficulty identifying what I am feeling.
Yes of course $0$ is lower bound of $A=\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \Bbb{N}\}$.
How to start?
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \Bbb{N}\}$.
Let us assume that $x\in A$. Then $x=\frac{1}{m}$ for some $m\in \Bbb{N}$.
Clearly, $0$ is lower bound of $A$. Therefore, $x=\frac{1}{m}\geq 0$ ,  $\forall m\in \Bbb{N}$ and $\forall x\in A$.

Let $\alpha$ be another lower bound of $A$.
We need to prove that $0\geq \alpha$!
If $0<\alpha$. Let $x\in A$. Then $x=\frac{1}{m}$ for some $m\in\Bbb{N}$. Then $\frac{1}{m}\geq\alpha>0,\forall m\in\Bbb{N}$. contradiction! since $\alpha$ is lower bound of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $e>0$ is a lb of that set. By Archimedian Property, there exists an $n \in N$ such that $n > 1/e$.
So $1/n<e$ for some $n$, which contradicts that $e>0$ is lb.

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Archimedean_Principle